# Node.Js google dataflow sinon stub is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, stub

Here is my function which calls google dataflow function

**index.js**

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const triggerDataflowJob = async (event, context) => {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
  });
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();
  const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();

  const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });
  const dataflowReqBody = dataflowRequest(projectId, event.bucket, event.name, context);
  return dataflow.projects.locations.templates.create(dataflowReqBody);
};

module.exports = { triggerDataflowJob };
```

My unit test for above function

**index.test.js**

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { triggerDataflowJob } = require('./index.js');

describe('Function: triggerDataflowJob', () => {
  it('should return success', async () => {
    const projectsStub = sinon.stub().returnsThis();
    const locationsStub = sinon.stub().returnsThis();

    const dataflowStub = sinon.stub(google, 'dataflow').callsFake(() => ({
      projects: projectsStub,
      locations: locationsStub,
      templates: sinon.stub(),
    }));

    const context = { eventId: '126348454' };
    const event = { bucket: 'test-bucket', name: 'test-file.json' };

    await triggerDataflowJob(event, context);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(dataflowStub);
  });
});
```

But I am getting below error when I run test.

```sh
1) Trigger Dataflow Job:
       Function: triggerDataflowJob
         should return success:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'templates' of undefined
      at triggerDataflowJob (index.js:12:38)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Can some one please help where is the issue? or what I am missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like the dataflow object you are getting back does not have a templates key within the location object.

Looking at your test, it looks like the dataflow object looks something like this:

```
const dataflow = {
   projects: {...},
   locations: {...},
   templates: {...}
}
```

In the return statement of the main function you are looking for templates within locations.

```
return dataflow.projects.locations.templates.create(dataflowReqBody);
```

If locations is suppose to have a templates key, then you may need to update your test and the way your mocking the object. If it is not suppose to have a templates key then you can update your return statement like so:

```
return dataflow.projects.templates.create(dataflowReqBody);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I am missing something in test case stub, return statement is correct. facing issue in stub of that method.